# How to wire for free

Tags: united-states, money-transfer, bank-of-america

My paycheck goes direct deposit into Wells Fargo Bank. I have a bank account at Bank of America that I need to feed. However, it costs $25 to wire money from WFB to BofA.

How can I get money from my WFB account to BofA without paying a fee? My best guess is Zelle - I have 2 phone numbers. Attach 1 number to WFB and 1 number to BofA and do it that way?

Comment: If both bank accounts are solely yours and use the same name, you should be able to set the other account up using "Add Non-Wells Fargo Account". See https://www.wellsfargo.com/online-banking/transfers/#:~:text=Can%20I%20transfer%20funds%20to,and%20when%20you%20need%20it.

Comment: "My paycheck goes direct deposit into Wells Fargo Bank" why?

Comment: If the WF account is a savings rather than checking, this could explain the lack of services. Otherwise, check the account for "bill pay" services and set up the BoA as a bill receiver.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't get your employer to update their records for your payment details ?

Answer (score 22):

You could also use an ACH transfer, which should be free of charge. The only catch is that it could take several business days to make the initial bank-to-bank link, and transfers generally take 1-2 business days (they can take longer but in my experience the money starts showing up the next business day if I initiated the transfer early enough in the day). So this won't be an option if you need that money at BofA ASAP.

Comment: ACH has some other limits. For example, my bank limits ACHs to $5k / day.

Comment: @fectin that's true. One of my banks has a $150k daily ACH limit ($600k/mo), and Zelle at the same bank has a $2,000 daily limit ($10k/mo), which actually surprises me how low it is. Check deposits are also limited as well (only $300 with next-day availability).

Answer (score 22):

In addition to all the other good answers, some of the newer payroll systems also support directly depositing part of your paycheck into another account. It might be worth exploring this as an option

Comment: This is what I was going to add. I can split between 4 different accounts, and do it either by % of check or specific dollar amount.

Comment: This is exactly what I do (twice a month) for an account that needs $500/month Direct Deposit to be fee-free.  Then I ACH transfer it to my main account.

Comment: If by "newer" you mean "within the past 25 years" then yeah, because that's how long I've been splitting my direct deposits.

Answer (score 13):

The ACH solution in [StanH's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/158658/32109) is a good one and I’ve had personal experience with WF ACH transfers to other banks. It worked just fine. The downside is it could take an extra day or so.

My solution to this problem was mobile check deposit. My WF checking came with a small supply of free checks. It might not be an attractive option if you have to buy checks, but they can be found for pretty cheap online. When you need to transfer money, write a check to yourself and mobile deposit to your BOA account. This solution also depends on the funds availability policy of mobile check deposits at BOA. My other bank made checks available the day of processing as long as they were mobile deposited by 7pm. It worked great!

Comment: Sometimes a check ends up taking weeks to clear (though banks may pretend otherwise, especially if your account balance is large enough to cover it).  ACH is a bit more predictable.  Also, sometimes banks will process a check as an ACH transfer, rather than via the check collection system.  Overall, this solution mostly works as well ACH and is often slightly more convenient.  However, I'd be a bit cautious about it.

Comment: Lol, hi, it’s me, a bank employee who will always pretend otherwise :) I haven’t encountered a check taking forever to clear in, well, forever. Unless there’s a problem with the check (missing info or illegible) or it’s physically lost at a bank branch. Which happens! Mobile deposit is an amazing invention, I’m a big fan!

Answer (score 2):

• Withdraw the money as cash then deposit it on the other bank. (I use this having no fee to withdraw and no fee to deposit using the atm... and being cash ther's no time between the operation and the moment the money is available on second account)
• Use ACH (what in EU is called a "SEPA Transfer") It may take a couple of days but it's usually free.
• Write yourself a check and cash it on the second bank
• Use Paypal and bind it to both accounts, load paypal from the first then deposit on the other.

Answer (score 0):

I use Paypal to transfer money between my accounts. You simply add your bank accounts to your Paypal account, then you can withdraw from one to feed the other for free. Only downside is that it does take a few days (usually 1-2) each time.

Comment: What country are you in?  If the US, then using PayPal like that is absurd; bank websites have features for transferring money just as quickly.

Comment: @RonJohn yeah, US. And sure, banks offer that too, but same as the OP's, most of my banks don't offer free transfers to other banks.

Comment: "most of my banks don't offer free transfers to other banks."  Don't offer free ACH from other banks to themselves?  I'm highly dubious.  And if actually true, you definitely need to find different banks.